# iis 7 https connection to page blocks any javascript and JQUERY

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, iis-7, https

I have an asp.net C# application hosted by IIS 7. I have installed a valid SSL Certificate and used [Security Switch](https://code.google.com/p/securityswitch/) in order to transfer each page from HTTP protocol to HTTPS.

On one of my pages, I use JQUERY. Specificly, I have a canvas that I draw some stuff on using Javascript, and also a GridView that I use the [tablesorter jquery plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) on.

Both does not work when I use the https connection, meaning that the canvas is empty, and the gridview isn't shown.

If I use the normal HTTP protocol everything works fine. Furthermore, If I don't use the tablesorter plugin on the gridview than I can see it even when using https.

I Suspect that the https connection is blocking my javascript, although when using google chrome and looking at the certificate(by clicking on the little lock at the address bar) it says "java script enabled".

My JQUERY itself is being refrenced at the MASTER PAGE of my website, while the other scripts (drawing on canvas and table sorter) are being imported on the page itslef in the header section such as this:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Looking at chromes console I see the following (only when using the https connection):

```
    [blocked] The page at **** ran insecure content from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow.
 
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://****/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js". 
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://****/Scripts/AquaGauge.js".
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://*****/Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js". 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js:1
[blocked] The page at https://***** ran insecure content from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow.

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

How can I make my javascript code also when using HTTPS connection?

Comment: Is jquery.tablesorter.js file loading using https? You can view error in console. See what error you get

Comment: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://******/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js".  uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: that seems to hint that the jquery lib has not been loaded

Comment: I know it is not loaded. Thats what I said, using https connection blocks my JQUERY and javascripts refrences.

Comment: Https should not block any .js files from being loaded/downloaded to the client machine. Have you tried the same in another browser such as IE?

Comment: yes, all is the same in every browser. also using http alone not gives me those errors, only using this page with the https protocol does

Comment: Checkout this link http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/ and see if protocol relative URL reference fixes your troubles ;o)

Comment: not really and it is not so relevant as all my scripts are local (I hold the files)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The javascript is being loaded threw a full path (https://yoursite.com/Script/jquery.js) although it is local, and not via file:// or anything else.

One must add threw Security Switch  also the links to these files.